# What is the format of the Maven Surefire plug-in <include> statement?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to run [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) with an include statement of:

```
<include>**/[A-R]*SeleniumTest.java</include>
<include>**/[A-R]**SeleniumTest.java</include>
<include>**/[A-R].*SeleniumTest.java</include>
```

But it does not seem to support any of these notations. What is the syntax of this expression? (Documentation link would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Maven Surefire Plugin follows the same semantics for configuring includes and excludes as Maven's FileSets.

You can find some details on how that works via [Maven: The Definitive Guide (Section 12.7)](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies-sect-filesets.html#ex-explicit-fileSet):

> The includes section uses a list of include elements, which contain path patterns. These patterns may contain wildcards such as '`**`' which matches one or more directories or '`*`' which matches part of a file name, and '`?`' which matches a single character in a file name

Answer (score 3):

The patterns used by maven's include tags follow the behavior of Ant's [Pattern](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) notation.

The [A-R] notation in your example is not supported, but you could use a combination of includes and excludes to narrow down the set of tests that get run.